# Why are all records deleted and not just one?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

To delete a game Session from a web service we have defined the following controller.

I expect one Session entity to be deleted, instead all records get deleted from the database.

```
SessionController.php

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/")
 * @Method({"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $repository = $this->getSessionRepository();
    $session = $repository->find($id);

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $em->remove($session);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('', 200);
}
```

The services.yml contains:

```
  sh.repository.session:
    class: ScavengerWebserviceBundle\Entity\SessionRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments:
      - 'ScavengerWebserviceBundle:Session'
/**
 * @return \Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\SessionRepository
 */
private function getSessionRepository()
{
    return $this->container->get('sh.repository.session');
}
```

The entity contains:

```
<?php

namespace Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity;

use Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\Battlezone;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToOne;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\SessionRepository")
 */
class Session
{

    const SESSION_ACTIVE = 0; //lol

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $mrX
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mrX", type="integer")
     */
    private $mrX;


     /**
     * @var integer $causer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="causer", type="integer")
     */
    private $causer = 0;


    /**
     * @var integer $statusCode
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status_code", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $statusCode = self::SESSION_ACTIVE;


    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="sessions", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Scavenger\WebserviceBundle\Entity\Battlezone", cascade={"all"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="battlezone_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $battlezone;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="start", type="integer") 
     */
    private $start = 0;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="end", type="integer")
     */
    private $end = 0;


    //a bunch of setters and getters ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've set "cascade=all" on $users field. I guess you have also the same cascade on "sessions" field in User entity, therefore if you remove some session object, all users related with that object will be removed as well AND all session objects related to these users will be removed too.

Answer (score 0):

When you called through find($id), it called the object pointing to the entire data store, whereas it has to be limited only to 1 entity WITHIN that data store where the object points.

Create an 'unsetData' in your `model` (if possible).

```
SessionController.php

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/")
 * @Method({"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $session = $this->getSessionRepository()->find($id);
    $session->unsetData(); // Logically, unset($session->dataToUnset);
    $em->persist();
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('', 200);
}
```

This is for the reference. I have not tried this code but, if it doesn't then, either you already know the path by now or if not, revert on comments and will get it sorted!